# Do not understand why I am getting error Syntax::tsntxi:

Tags: functions, syntax, warning-messages

```
F[k1_, k2_, λ1_, λ2_, δ_, w1_, w2_] := 
  (1 - Exp[-(w1/λ1)^k1])*(1 - Exp[-(w2/λ2)^k2])*
    Exp {[(1 - (1 - Exp[-(w1/λ1)^k1]))^-δ + (1 + (1 - Exp[-(w2/λ2)^k2]))^-δ]^(1/-δ)};

f[k1_, k2_, λ1_, λ2_, δ_, w1_, w2_] = D[F[k1, k2, λ1, λ2, δ, w1, w2], w1, w2];

Plot3D[f[2.3, 2.5, 6, 8, 0.001, x, y], {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]

Plot3D[f[2.3, 2.5, 6, 8, 1, x, y], {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]

Plot3D[f[2.3, 2.5, 6, 8, 10, x, y], {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

I am trying run the code above. 1t gives an error message:

> Syntax::tsntxi: "[(1-(1-Exp[-(w1/λ1)^k1]))^-δ+(1+(1-Exp[-(w2/λ2)^k2]))^-δ]" is incomplete; more input is needed.

I checked for a syntax error but there isn't any. Formula used is also correct, so what can  be the problem?

Comment: "i checked for syntax error but there isn't." - did you carefully look at the syntax highlighting and notice any pink delimiters (parentheses, brackets)?

Comment: Your definition of `F` clearly has syntax errors.

Comment: Square brackets are (to first order) strictly for function calls and for `Part` extraction when they appear in pairs. Curly brackets are strictly for `List`s.

Answer (score 4):

There was a wrong bracket in F. Also do not use { as a normal bracket, and second you wrote Exp{[ which has to be either {Exp[ or (Exp[ .

```
F[k1_, k2_, λ1_, λ2_, δ_, w1_, w2_] := 
  (1 - Exp[-(w1/λ1)^k1]) (1 - Exp[-(w2/λ2)^k2]) 
    (Exp[(1 - (1 - Exp[-(w1/λ1)^k1]))^(-δ) + (1 + (1 - Exp[-(w2/λ2)^k2]))^-δ]^(1/-δ))
```